# Laravel :error with Update composer and create progect

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel version 6.17.1,php 7.4.2 and composer version 1.9.3,When I composer update, I see the following problem:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Deprecation Notice: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted
>   as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the
>   current behavior in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:233
>
> Deprecation Notice: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted
>   as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the
>   current behavior in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:233
>
> Deprecation Notice: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted
>   as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the
>   current behavior in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php:233
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The "27.0.0.1/index.html"
>   file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

So, the question is how to update without error ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried updating composer itself by downloading a newer composer.phar from their site? (might get rid of the deprication notices). also "27.0.0.1/index.html" looks like it's missing a 1, you might have mistyped `127.0.0.1` somewhere (that IP is localhost: every machines IP to itself).

Comment: I created a new project and did not modify it, but when I update it the previous error appears, and also when I self-update it the update composer.phar will complete successfully and without errors.
Is it possible that I need to download packages?

Comment: Can you paste your composer.json in your question?